# Observation or observations

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I am so confused about the singular and plural forms of observation in academic writing.

Here is an example:

> The improved model showed a better performance than the prior model based on **observations**.

The context of the example sentence is:
I compared the improved model with the prior model in terms of different variables (e.g., precipitation, temperature, radiation). Due to so, different observational datasets were used.

Should I use **observation** or **observations**?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you mean number of observations? If it is the number of rows you are talking about in your data set, then it should be observations. But I am not sure if that is what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

*observation* can be both a singular and [plural](https://www.yourdictionary.com/observations). If you have more than one *observation* for your testing, you use a plural form. In this context, *in my opinion*, you may go for a plural word because when you test a software tool with its previous versions, you have many parameters each one having a particular way to observe/mark its efficacy.

So, I would prefer a plural word.

Comment: There is something very fishy in the question. He says *"I compared the improved model with the prior model in **terms of different variables**"* He does not say anything about changing the number of observations in the new model. The new model simply has a different set of variables. Then he says *"different observational datasets were used"* which indicates the new model used a data set with different number of observations. I have a strong feeling he is using the wrong word (i.e., it should be variables not observations).

Comment: I believe it should be *"... the new model performed better than the prior model because the **model specification** was revised (or due to the inclusion of additional variables) "* May be I have gone too far.

Answer (score 0):

**Longman Dictionary:**

> **Observation:** the process of watching something or someone carefully
>   for a period of time.

**Collins Dictionary:**

> **Observation:** is the action or process of carefully watching someone or
>   something.

The observation is an action or process carried out by singular existence.
Which gives us the conclusion it is **one point of view in a time** can be looking at multiple objects **yet it is a singular action**.

As you can see in term of multiple action of observing we can say "observations" but not if a singular action is taking place;

> -I compared the improved model with the prior model in terms of temperature.

Singular action is taking place so it should be **observation**.

> -I compared the improved model with the prior model in terms of different variables (e.g., precipitation, temperature, radiation).

Multiple actions are taking place so it should be **observations**.

Hope it helps..